# Who are all of the characters in this paranormal genre poster?

Tags: character-identification

Who are all of the characters identified in [the poster by Josan Gonzalez and Laurie Greasley](https://www.slashfilm.com/josan-gonzalez-and-laurie-greasley-the-raid-2-print/)?

[image: Original poster]

[image: Poster washed out with numbers]

Comment: Missing a number for the pumpkin man and the guy between 67 and 68. You also seem to have arbitrarily numerbered some (perhaps insignificant) objects but not others.

Answer (score 11):

1. Street Schizo (John Carpenter's *Prince of Darkness*/actor Alice Cooper)
2. John Trent (*In The Mouth of Madness*)
3. ???
4. Andy Barclay (Child's Play, wearing his jacket as seen in the "Frying the Doctor" scene -- Pointing towards the "Good Guys" toy box.)
5. Inspector Gadget? Or possibly Lt. Lefty Enright (*Texas Chainsaw Massacre 2*/actor Dennis Hopper).  Same two-tone western jacket, hat, and tie.
6. Little girl from John Carpenter's *Assault*?
7. April O'Neil
8. Frank Drebin (*The Naked Gun*)
9. ???
10. Chucky (*Child’s Play*)
11. Good Guys doll box (*Child's Play*)
12. ???
13. ???
14. Freddy (*Nightmare on Elm Street*)
15. Rays Occult Books (*Ghostbusters 2*)
16. The Crypt Keeper (*Tales from the crypt*)
17. ???
18. Slimer
19. Dr. Carl Hill (*Re-Animator*/actor David Gale)
20. Crawford Tillinghast (*From Beyond*/actor Jeffery Combs)
21. Dr. Katherine McMichaels (*From Beyond*/actress Barbara Crampton)
22. Bubba Brownlee (*From Beyond*/actor Ken Foree)
23. The Resonator (*From Beyond*)
24. Johann Krauss (*Hellboy II: The Golden army*)
25. Vial containing the essence of Satan (John Carpenter's *Prince of Darkness*)
26. The Shape (John Carpenter's *Halloween*)
27. Danny's tricycle (*The Shining*)
28. *Hellraiser* poster
29. Bounty hunter (*Critters*)
30. Pinhead (*Hellraiser*)
31. Crite (*Critters*)
32. ???
33. Snake Plissken (*Escape from New York*)
34. Jason (*Friday the 13th*)
35. Captain Rhodes (*Day of the Dead*/actor Joe Pilalo)
36. Brain (*Gremlins*)
37. "Sweets to the Sweet" is graffiti on wall in *Candyman*.
38. Leprechaun
39. Hannibal “The Cannibal” Lector
40. Bride of Chucky (*Bride of Chucky*)
41. Protector 1 (*Chopping Mall*)
42. Critter (*Critters*)
43. Stripe (*Gremlins*)
44. ???
45. Daffy (*Gremlins 2*)
46. George (*Gremlins 2*)
47. Lenny (*Gremlins 2*)
48. Commander Helena Braddock (*Ghosts of Mars*)
49. Possibly Franklin Hunt (Bone Tomahawk)?
    49bis. Critter (*Critters*)
50. Max Walker (*Timecop*)
51. The Driver (*Drive*, played by Ryan Gosling, in werewolf form (["Ryan Gosling's wheelman character is a werewolf"](http://www.mtv.com/news/2809825/refn-gosling-werewolf/)))
52. Doomguy (*Doom*)
53. Leatherface (*The Texas Chainsaw Massacre*)
54. ???
55. kids (*Village of the Damned*)
56. Greta (*Gremlins 2*)
57. Jack Goodman (*An American Werewolf in London*)
58. Van Helsing (*Van Helsing*)
59. Mulder (*X-Files*)
60. Scully (*X-Files*)
61. Officer Matthew Cordell (*Maniac Cop*)
62. Taryn (*A Nightmare on Elm Street 3: Dream Warriors*)
63. Will Stanton (*A Nightmare on Elm Street 3: Dream Warriors*)
64. ???
65. Kincaid (*A Nightmare on Elm Street 3: Dream Warriors*)
66. Abe Sapien (*Hellboy*)
67. Ghoul version of Big Ben (1985 film *House*)
68. Bishop? (*Aliens*)
69. Ash Williams (Evil Dead)
70. ???
71. ???
72. John Nada (*They Live*)
73. *They Live* aliens (*They Live*)
74. McReady (*The Thing*)
75. Jack Burton (*Big trouble in Little China*)
76. Alien queen (*Aliens*)
77. Facehugger and eggs (*Alien*/*Aliens*)
78. Alien (Aliens)
    78bis. "They live we sleep" tag (*They Live*)
79. Head crab (*Half-life*)
80. Toombs (*The X-Files*)
81. Boomer (Left 4 Dead)
82. Gordon Freeman (*Half-life*)
83. Milo (Bad Milo)
84. Cheddar Goblin (*Mandy*)
85. Gizmo (*Gremlins*)
86. Seth Brundle (*The Fly*)
87. Ellie (*The Last of Us*)
88. Joel (*The Last of Us*)
89. Pickle Rick (*Rick and Morty*)
    89bis. Teleporter pod (*The Fly*)
90. Norris-Thing (*The Thing*)
91. Flood Infection Form (Halo)
92. Merman (*Cabin in the Woods*)
93. Paper boat that was swept into the sewer (Stephen King's *It*)
94. Gravity drive core (*Event Horizon*)
95. [Cacodemon](https://doomwiki.org/wiki/Cacodemon_(Doom_2016)) (*Doom*)
96. Puzzle box (*Hellraiser*)
97. The Cronos Device (mechanical golden scarab beetle from Guillermo del Toro's *Cronos*)
98. Necronomicon
99. Homicidal tyre ([*Rubber*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1612774/)).
100. Mola Ram (*Temple of Doom*)
101. Stones of Shiva (*Temple of Doom*)
102. VHS cassette (*The Ring*)
103. Samara Morgan (*The Ring*)
104. Demogorgon (*Stranger Things*)
105. Dianoga (*Star Wars IV: A New Hope*)
106. Pale Man (*Pan's Labyrinth*)
107. Hellboy (*Hellboy*)
108. It (*It*)
109. Isaac Clarke (Dead Space)

Comment: I added a temporary "89bis" for the teleporter but maybe this​could use a grid instead of numbers

Comment: If you intend for others to help fill this in, you should mark your answer as a Community Wiki.

Comment: Is this a mummy arm below #44?

Comment: 82. Halflife Garry?

Comment: What does "bis" mean?

Comment: I'm pretty sure 106 is the Pale Man from Pan's Labyrinth.

Comment: @Martha it means "twice".

Comment: Could 73 be "They Live" aliens in SWAT gear?

Comment: 9 from Starship Troopers?

Comment: 58 looks like Van Helsing (crossbow, wide-brim hat, trench coat)

Comment: 5 is not Inspector gadget, the hat is completely wrong.

Comment: 61 resembles Bruce Campbell's character in _Maniac Cop_.  Not certain about the jacket.

Comment: 41 could be the robot from *Chopping Mall*, but more likely from *Evolver*.

Comment: I've converted this answer to a Community Wiki post after [meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12194/31394). Everyone, feel free to [edit] in your contributions instead of commenting :-)