# Who are the (numerous) patrons of the Warp Core Cafe?

Tags: character-identification, crossovers, fandom

I came across this very awesome, very large illustration by Jeff Carlisle named [*Another Night at the Warp Core Cafe*](http://jeffcarlisle.com/node/514?size=_original&fbclid=IwAR0p54lfTKdZOUZhHZy2-7G1HISoCpo20-w-rl1nbqMCSITebVlNWxcaONc). It features a vast amount of characters from a vast amount of franchises. I was hoping our community would rise to the challenge and help identify as many as possible!

[image: Warp Core Cafe]

Comment: @Stormblessed Nice work on the key. I did not think to do a grid and was assigning a unique number to each person/thing.... IMO you found a much better/easier way.

Comment: To those voting to close as too broad, [we already](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171218/can-we-identify-all-the-characters-in-this-universe-113-poster) have [several questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/199089/who-are-all-of-the-characters-in-this-paranormal-genre-poster) set [in this format](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195553/can-we-identify-all-the-characters-in-this-ultimate-space-battle-poster), so there is precedent.

Comment: Is Harrison Ford the only actor on there twice (as Rick Deckard and Han Solo)? For instance there are a few people from *Dune*, is Sean Young somewhere as Chani as well as Rachel?

Comment: Or for that matter, Ben Browder as both John Crichton (*Farscape*) and Cameron Mitchell (*Stargate SG1*)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[image: Warp Core Café with a grid with text in Menlo]

**A1:**

**A2:**

- [USS Defiant](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Defiant_(2370)) (*Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*)
- Hammerhead fighter (*Space: Above and Beyond*)

**A3:**

- [Borg Cube](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borg_cube) (*Star Trek*)
- X-Wing (*Star Wars*)

**A4:**

- The *Death Star II* (*Star Wars*)

**A5:**

**A6:**

- Babylon 5 (in the background, spanning a large area from **A6** to **D3**)
- [Klingon D7-class battlecruiser](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/D7_class) (*Star Trek*) (Also A7)
- Space Vampire Mothership (*Lifeforce*)

**A7:**

- [Romulan Warbird](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/D%27deridex_class) [behind D7 and White Star] (*Star Trek: The Next Generation*, *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*, *Star Trek: Voyager*) (slightly green, Also A6, A8, B6, B7)
- White Star (*Babylon 5*) (also **B7**)

**A8:**

- [Romulan Bird of Prey](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Romulan_Bird-of-Prey_(22nd_century)) (*Star Trek: TOS*)

**A9:**

- Zanti, *[The Zanti Misfits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Zanti_Misfits)* (*Outer Limits* 1963)

**A10:**

- Zanti, *[The Zanti Misfits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Zanti_Misfits)* (*Outer Limits* 1963)

**A11:**

**A12:**

- Space Herpes (*Ice Pirates*)

---

**B1:**

- Colonial Viper (*Battlestar Galactica*)
- "Nell" ship (*Battle Beyond the Stars* (1980))

**B2:**

- Imperial Star Destroyer (*Star Wars*)
- Ghost (*Star Wars Rebels*)

**B3:**

- UD-4L Cheyenne Dropship, Sulaco (*Aliens*, 1986) (top middle half of tile)

**B4:**

- [USS Enterprise-D](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-D)) (*Star Trek: The Next Generation*)

**B5:**

- Star Fury (*Babylon 5*) [Also B6, C5, C6]

**B6:**

- Warp core  [Trough B6:K7]
- [Eagle Transporter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_Transporter), [*Space: 1999*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_1999) (1975)
- Fighter (*Buck Rogers in the 25th Century*)

**B7:**

- Eagle 5 (*Spaceballs*)

**B8:**

- Battlestar Galactica (*Battlestar Galactica*)
- Moya (*Farscape*) (Also B9)
- Jetfire (*Transformers*) (Also B9)

**B9:**

- Moya (*Farscape*) continued.

**B10:**

- Zanti, *[The Zanti Misfits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Zanti_Misfits)* (*Outer Limits* 1963)

**B11:**

- Gremlin (*Gremlins*)

**B12:**

- [Ceti Eel](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ceti_eel), a parasitic arthropod from Ceti Alpha V ([Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_II:_The_Wrath_of_Khan), 1982) (also C12)
- Crystal Bat (*The Dark Crystal*)

---

**C1:**

- The *Millennium Falcon* (*Star Wars*)

**C2:**

- USS Palomino (*The Black Hole*, 1979)

**C3:**

- Bebop (*Cowboy Bebop*) (also D3)
- Paranoid battlesuit (*Gall Force: Eternal Story*) (also at C4, D4)

**C4:**

- Planet Express Ship (*Futurama*)
- Ravager M-ship, The Milano (*Guardians of the Galaxy*) (also at C3, D4)

**C5:**

- Radiant VII (*Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace*)
- USS Enterprise (*Star Trek: The Original Series*)

**C6:**

- Narcissus, Nostromo Lifeboat (*Alien* 1979, *Aliens* 1986)

**C7:**

**C8:**

- Engineer Ship (*Alien* 1979, *Prometheus* 2012)
- Nebulon-B Frigate (hospital ship, *Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back*, *Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi*)

**C9:**

- USS Discovery One (2001: A Space Odyssey)

**C10:**

**C11:**

- Zanti, *[The Zanti Misfits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Zanti_Misfits)* (Outer Limits 1963)

**C12:**

- [Ceti Eel](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ceti_eel), a parasitic arthropod from Ceti Alpha V ([Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_II:_The_Wrath_of_Khan), 1982) (continued from B12)

---

**D1:**

- Insignia: Cylon Empire (Battlestar Galactica)
- Insignia: Colonial Warrior (Battlestar Galactica)

**D2:**

- Insignia: Rebel Alliance (Star Wars, continues D1)

**D3:**

- Imperial Probe Droid (*Star Wars*)

**D4:**

- *Close Encounters of the Third Kind* mothership (also **D5**)
- Viper (BSG)

**D5:**

- Rodger Young (Starship Troopers)

**D6:**

- USS Voyager (Star Trek: Voyager)
- Serenity (Firefly)

**D7:**

- USS *Swinetrek* (*The Muppet Show*: "Pigs in Space")
- Giant dragonfly "insect", [*Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nausica%C3%A4_of_the_Valley_of_the_Wind_(film)) (1984)

**D8:**

**D9:**

- Insignia: Klingon Empire (Star Trek)

**D10:**

- Max (*Flight of the Navigator*, 1986)

**D11:**

- Pit Droid folded up (*Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace*)

**D12:**

- Impossible Man (Marvel Comics)

---

**E1:**

- Bioraptor (*Riddick*)

**E2:**

**E3:**

**E4:**

- Insignia: Galactic Empire (Star Wars)
- Insignia: Robotech Defense Force (Robotech)

**E5:**

- Insignia: ThunderCats

**E6:**

- Insignia: Tron's chest symbol (Tron)

**E7:**

- Urskeks mandala of The Great Conjunction (The Dark Crystal)

**E8:**

- Lazerbeak (Transformers)

**E9:**

**E10:**

**E11:**

- Wall-E and Eve from *Wall-E*

**E12:**

- Egg and Facehugger (*Alien* franchise)

---

**F1:**

- Atari logo
- Kilroy from the *Mr. Roboto* music video by Styx

**F2:**

- Maximilian, [*The Black Hole*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Hole) (1979)

**F3:**

- *Robot Jox* mech fight: Achilles (left) vs Alexander (right)

**F4:**

- V.I.N.CENT, *The Black Hole*

**F5:**

- Spider-Man, in alien symbiote suit (Marvel Comics)

**F6:**

**F7:**
-Optimus Prime (Transformers) (also F8)

**F8:**

- Iron Giant from *The Iron Giant* (left hand appears in G9 and H9)

**F9:**

- Thunder Road, modified Tilt-A-Whirl car (Explorer's 1985)

**F10:**

- [C-57D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-57D) *[Forbidden Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_Planet)* (1956)
- Jupiter 2, *Lost in Space* (1965)

**F11:**

**F12:**

- Huey, Dewey, and Louie from *Silent Running* (1972)

---

**G1:**

- "They Live We Sleep" tag from *They Live* (1988) (continued in G2)
- Stargate Ring (Stargate)

**G2:**

- Pan Am logo and Orion III Space Clipper (*2001: A Space Odyssey*)

**G3:**

- Kuato Lives tag from *Total Recall* (1990)
- Weyland-Yutani symbol, *Alien* franchise

**G4:**

- V.I.N.CENT, *The Black Hole* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Hole) (1979)
- Logo: Buy'N Large (Wall-E)

**G5:**

- Robocop
- Logo: Omni Consumer Products (Robocop)
- Diva, *The Fifth Element*
- Zorg Industries Logo, *The Fifth Element*
- Gypsy, *Mystery Science Theater 3000* (also G6)
- Omar & Angel (Rock & Rule, 1983)

**G6:**

**G7:**

- Flynn's Arcade sign (Tron, 1982)

**G8:**

- Weebo (Flubber)
- crystals from *Lifeforce*

**G9:**

- Borg Queen (Star Trek: First Contact)
- Visitors' poster, defaced by the Resistance (*V*)

**G10:**

- Rocket Cycle (*Flash Gordon*, 1980)
- Nomad (*Star Trek: TOS*, episode "The Changeling")

**G11:**

- Tripod, *[The War of the Worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_of_the_Worlds_(1953_film))* (1953)
- Endor Shield Generator (*Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi*)
- StarChaser (*StarChaser: The Legend of Orin*, 1985)

**G12:**

- Lambda-class T-4a shuttle (*Star Wars*)

**G13:**

- Breetai, a Zentraedi commander (*Robotech: The Macross Saga*)

---

**H1:**

- Bo (*Mighty Orbots*)
- Barbarella (*Barbarella*)
- Ted Theodore Logan & Bill S. Preston Esq. of the 'Wyld Stallyns' (Bill & Ted's Excellent Adventure, 1989)

**H2:**

- Blue Sun advertisement (*Firefly*)
- A female Vulcan [**maybe a specific character?**] (*Star Trek*)
- Maria from *Metropolis* (android form)
- Feyd Rautha (*Dune*, 1984)
- Silica (Starchaser: The Legend of Orin, 1985)

**H3:**

- [TARDIS](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Doctor%27s_TARDIS) (*Doctor Who*)
- Oola, a Twi'lek dancer at Jabba's palace (*Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi*)
- Leeloo (*The Fifth Element*)
- Rystáll Sant (*Star Wars*) (also G3, G4, H4)

**H4:**

- Jabba the Hutt (*Star Wars*)
- A Skeksis (from *The Dark Crystal*) ([source](https://www.facebook.com/JeffCarlisleArt/photos/a.469037131059/10157036598691060/?type=3&theater)
- Figrin D'an and the Modal Nodes (Star Wars)

**H5:**

- Sy Snootles (*Star Wars*)

**H6:**

- Data (*Star Trek: the Next Generation*)
- Wak Wak (*Explorers*, 1985)

**H7:**

- Klaatu (hand raised), *The Day The Earth Stood Still* (1951)
- Barquin D'an (Max Rebo Band) (*Star Wars: A New Hope* (1977))
- Monolith (*2001: A Space Odyssey*)
- Tall alien (*Close Encounters of the Third Kind*)

**H8:**

- (rear) Gort, (*The Day the Earth Stood Still*, 1951)
- Robot (*Lost in Space*, 1965-1968)
- Robby the Robot (*Forbidden Planet*)
- Johnny 5 (Short Circuit, 1986)

**H9:**

- Marvin, *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* (film)
- Cheetara, *ThunderCats*
- Lion-O, *ThunderCats*
- Statue of The Lawgiver (*Planet of the Apes*)

**H10:**

- Nomad - ST:TOS "The Changeling"
- Atreides Transport (Dune)
- Starfleet shuttlecraft (*Star Trek*)
- Luke Skywalker's X-34 landspeeder (*Star Wars - Episode IV: A New Hope*)

**H11:**

- Starbug (Red Dwarf)
- Jake’s ship  from *The Cat from Outer Space*

**H12:**

- Superman
- Mooncake (*Final Space*)
- Rick, Morty, Mrs Meeseeks, and Rick's UFO (Rick & Morty)
- Korben Dallas's flying Taxi (The Fifth Element, H13 - I12)

---

**I1:**

- Ohno, (*Mighty Orbots*)
- Skeletor (HeMan and the Masters of the Universe)

**I2:**

**I3:**

- "Marta" Orion Girl (Star Trek:TOS "Whom Gods Destroy") [Also J3]
- Twiki, *Buck Rogers in the 25th Century*

**I4:**

- [Lirin Car'n](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lirin_Car%27n) of the Modal Nodes (*Star Wars*)

**I5:**

**I6:**

- Dominar Rygel XVI (Farscape)

**I7:**

**I8:**

- [Dalek](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Dalek) (*Doctor Who*)
- [Cyberman](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Cyberman) (*Doctor Who*)
- Bender (*Futurama*)
- Alien, *Earth vs. the Flying Saucers* (1956)
- Cylon - Battlestar Galactica (original series)
- Kryton, Cat, Lister & Rimmer (I9) (Red Dwarf)
- Two Andorians (*Star Trek*)
- Ka D'Argo - Farscape

**I9:**

- Seven of Nine (Star Trek: Voyager)
- Mac, Zeebo, and Wiploc (*Earth Girls Are Easy*)
- Aviana & Mizzo (Starchaser: The Legend of Orin, continues I10)
- Lumpy (A guess, but all of Chewbacca's family are sitting there, the other two in I11.  Just can't tell them apart.  *The Star Wars Holiday Special*)
- Zozo (The Adventures of the Galaxy Rangers)
- The Moon (*Le Voyage Dans la Lun / A Trip to the Moon*)

**I10:**

- Borg (*Star Trek*)
- Thark (John Carter of Mars)
- [Martians](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Martians_(Mars_Attacks!)) from *Mars Attacks*
- Martian from The War of the Worlds
- Itchy & Malla (A guess, but all of Chewbacca's family are sitting there, the third in I10.  Just can't tell them apart.  *The Star Wars Holiday Special*)
- 7-90 (*Lexx*)
- Dark Helmet (*Spaceballs*)
- Harry (*Harry and the Hendersons*)
- Gamorrean guard (*Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi*)
- A Thermian male (Mathesar?) in human form (*Galaxy Quest*)
- Gwen Demarco / Tawny Madison (*Galaxy Quest*)

**I11:**

- Waldo Zeptic (The Adventures of the Galaxy Rangers)
- Gamorrean guard (*Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi*)
- Martian Girl (Lisa Marie), *Mars Attacks* (1996) (Also J11)

**I12:**

- Chig in space suit (Space: Above and Beyond) (bordering I11)
- Predator
- Xenomorph from the *Alien* franchise
- Kang and Kodos (behind window) (*The Simpsons*)
- Korben Dallas (*The Fifth Element*)
- Sil, in alien form (*Species*)

**I13:**

- Zorak (Space Ghost, Coast to Coast)

---

**J1:** Micronauts, Repto (Mego Micronauts Series 4/5, http://micronauts.wikia.com/wiki/Repto)

**J2:**

- A Porg (*Star Wars*)
- A Tribble (*Star Trek*)

**J3:**

**J4:**

**J5:**

**J6:**

- (?) Horta (*Star Trek*)
- Morn (*Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*)

**J7:**

- A Quarren (*Star Wars*)
- Alien clown from *Killers Klowns from Outer Space*
- Jem'Hadar (*Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*)
- Scorpious (*Farscape*)

**J8:**

- Agents K and J (*Men in Black*)
- Jar-Jar Binks (*Star Wars*)
- Ruby Rhod (*The Fifth Element*) (also in JK8/9)
- [Kai Opaka](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Opaka) (*Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*)
- Captain Jack Harkness (*Doctor Who*)

**J9:**

- Vina as an Orion slave girl (*Star Trek: TOS*)
- R2-KT (*Star Wars*)
- Gorn (*Star Trek: TOS*)
- Det. George Francisco (*Alien Nation*) (Either that's him, or he's the man in the blue suit over in J12.  It could be either one.  But I think it's this one.)

**J10:**

- Ewoks (*Star Wars*)
- [Mugato](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mugato) (*Star Trek: TOS*)
- Excalbian (*Star Trek: TOS*, episode "The Savage Curtain")
- [Talosians](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Talosian) (*Star Trek: TOS*)
- [Jean-Luc Picard](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jean-Luc_Picard) (*Star Trek: The Next Generation*)
- [William T. Riker](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/William_T._Riker) (*Star Trek: The Next Generation*)

**J11:**

- [Nog](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nog) and [Rom](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rom) (*Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*)
- Two [Breen](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Breen) soldiers
- [Q](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q) in his [Judge costume](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/File:Q_as_judge,_2364.jpg) (*Star Trek: The Next Generation*)
- [Lore](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lore) (*Star Trek: The Next Generation*)
- [Boba Fett](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Boba_Fett) (*Star Wars*)
- [Spock](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spock) (*Star Trek: The Original Series*)
- [Leonard McCoy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Leonard_McCoy) (*Star Trek: The Original Series*)
- Nien Nunb (*Star Wars*)

**J12:**

- [Darth Talon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Talon) (*Star Wars* (Legends))
- [Mace Windu](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mace_Windu) (*Star Wars*)
- [BB-8](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/BB-8) (*Star Wars: The Force Awakens*)
- A Vorvon (*Buck Rogers in the 25th Century*, ["Space Vampire"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0533111/))
- A Red Lectroid (*The Adventures of Buckaroo Banzai Across the 8th Dimension*)
- (?) Michael (*The Good Place*)

---

**K1:**

**K2:**

- [Darth Vader](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Vader) (*Star Wars*) (only right arm and buttons of the suit visible)

**K3:**

- Wuher, the bartender from Mos Eisley cantina (*Star Wars*)

**K4:**

- Kuato (*Total Recall*, 1990)
- He-Man (*He-Man and the Masters of the Universe* cartoon, 1983-1985) (continued in K5)

**K5:**

- Dragon noodle parlor neon sign (*Blade Runner*) [also in K4]
- Lightsaber (*Star Wars*)

**K6:**

- Salacious B. Crumb (*Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi*, 1983)
- Ackmena (*The Star Wars Holiday Special*)

**K7:**

- Damar (Star Trek: Deep Space Nine) - Garak wasn't usually seen in a Cardassian military uniform, and Damar was more known for drinking than Dukat
- Roth'h'ar Sarris, main antagonist of *Galaxy Quest* (also in L7)
- Kabe (*Star Wars*)

**K8:**

- Tarfful (*Star Wars*)
- Ripley and Jonesy (cat) from *Alien*

**K9:**

- Alien from *Mars Attacks* (being strangled)
- Stormtroopers, *Star Wars*
- Paul Atreides from *Dune*, pre-Muad'Dib attire

**K10:**

- Stormtroopers (*Star Wars*)
- James T. Kirk (*Star Trek: TOS*)
- Drac Jeriba and Zammis (*Enemy Mine*)
- Qui-Gon Jinn (*Star Wars*) (also L10)

**K11:**

- Han (*Star Wars*)
- Leia (*Star Wars*)
- Greedo (*Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope*)
- C3-PO (*Star Wars*)

**K12:**

- Momaw Nadon (*Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope*)
- Ewok, possibly Chief Chirpa? (*Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi*)
- Admiral Ackbar (*Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi*)
- Col. Wilma Deering (*Buck Rogers in the 25th Century*, 1979)
- Senator Padmé Amidala (*Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones*) - No, she's not in this version. She is visible here in an older, less populated version of Jeff Carlisle's artwork that was posted on Reddit in late July, 2018, however.
- Scout Trooper (*Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi*)

---

**L1:**

- Ming the Merciless (*Flash Gordon*, 1980) — chest and arms
- Tom Servo and Crow T. Robot (*MST3K*) (continued in M1)

**L2:**

- [Simon game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_%28game%29)
- Dancing Alien (*Spaceballs*)

**L3:**

- Max Headroom (on TV screen)
- Saurian brandy bottle (*Star Trek*)
- Kanar bottle (*Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*)
- Flag of the United Citizen Federation / Terran Federation (*Starship Troopers*)

**L4:**

- Aviana's riding helmet (StarChaser: The Legend of Orin - For an obscure 80's cartoon, this has been showing up a lot here, this is the 5th reference I've found)
- Glaive from *Krull*

**L5:**

- Guinan (*Star Trek: The Next Generation*)
- H.A.L. 9000 (*2001: A Space Odyssey*)
- Zik-Zak Corp. logo (*Max Headroom series*) (also L4)
- Sword of Omens (Thunder Cats, continued in L6)

**L6:**

- Gigolo Joe (*A.I. Artificial Intelligence* 2001) (continued in M6)
- Facehugger as seen in Ash's lab (*Alien*)

**L7:**

- Princess Aura (*Flash Gordon*, 1980, [source](https://www.imdb.com/media/rm4246478336/nm0001560))

**L8:**

- [Pampy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Pampy), Twi'lek aide to Senator Orn Free Taa (*Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones*)

**L9:**

- Jessica Atreides (*Dune*)
- [Communicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicator_(Star_Trek)) from *Star Trek* (on the floor) (?)
- Nyota Uhura, *Star Trek: TOS* (?)

**L10:**

- Rose (*Star Wars*)
- Finn (*Star Wars*)
- Aeryn Sun (*Farscape*) (also M10)
- John Crichton (*Farscape*) (also M10)
- Mara Jade (*Star Wars*)

**L11:**

- [R2-D2](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/R2-D2) (*Star Wars*)
- [Thrawn](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mitth%27raw%27nuruodo) (*Star Wars*)
- Waldo (robot-version) (*Where's Waldo?*) (continued in L12,M11,M12)

**L12:**

- Scout trooper (*Star Wars*)
- (Possibly) Luke Skywalker's Hands (*Star Wars*) (continued M12)
- Schwartz Ring (*Spaceballs*)
- Erin "Dart" Bia O'Rourke-Singh, white-haired woman, from the 2nd Atari Force team

---

**M1:**

- Tom Servo and Crow T. Robot (*MST3K*) (continued from L1)

**M2:**

- "Obey and Conform" sign (*They Live*)

**M3:**

- Quark (Star Trek: Deep Space Nine)
- RYLOS license plate (*The Last Starfighter*) (also **M2**/**N2**/**N3**)

**M4:**

**M5:**

- [Rick Dekard](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Rick_Deckard) and [Rachael](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Rachael), *Blade Runner*

**M6:**

- Inara Serra, *Firefly*

**M7:**

- Krite ([Critters](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090887/))

**M8:**

- Cover of [*Starlog* Number 1](https://archive.org/details/starlog_magazine-001), featuring Kirk, Spock, and the USS *Enterprise* from *Star Trek*

**M9:**

**M10:**

- Mutant, *This Island Earth* (1955)

**M11:**

**M12:**

---

**N1:**

- Thermian (*Galaxy Quest*)
- Bucket of Popplers from Fishy Joe's (*Futurama*) (bucket visible in **W1**)

**N2:**

- Donald Kessler and Barbra Land, *Mars Attacks*

**N3:**

- Gizmo, *Gremlins*
- Londo Mollari, *Babylon 5*
- Jrrr of the planet Omicron Persei 8 (*Futurama*)

**N4:**

- Baby Groot (Guardians of the Galaxy Vol 2)

**N5:**

**N6:**

- Christopher Johnson, the alien from *District 9* (continued in N7)

**N7:**

- Teddy Bear from *AI* <s>*Ted*, or *SuperTed*?</s>

**N8:**

- Rocket Raccoon (Guardians of the Galaxy)
- E.T.
- Rick's portal gun (*Rick and Morty*)

**N9:**

- Alien from *Invasion of the Saucer-Men*
- Saurian brandy bottle (*Star Trek*)
- Mac (*Mac and Me*), with Big Mac and fries from McDonald's

**N10:**

- Howard the Duck (*Marvel Comics*)
- Paul ([*Paul*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_(film)))
- Alf ([*Alf*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALF_(TV_series)))

**N11:**

**N12:**

- The Great Gazoo, *The Flintstones* (1965)
- Gaff's unicorn origami, *Blade Runner*
- Tribbles (*Star Trek*)

---

**W1:**

- A Horga'hn from Planet Risa (*Star Trek: The Next Generation*)

**W2:**

- G'Kar (*Babylon 5*)

**W3:**

**W4:**

- Annelids/worm coffee aliens (*Men In Black*)

**W5:**

- Chiana, also X5 (*Farscape*)
- MSE-6-series repair droid (*Star Wars*)

**W6:**

**W7:**

- Arthur Dent, (*The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* film)

**W8:**

- Yoda (*Star Wars*)

**W9:**

- Maz Kanata, *Star Wars*
- Auryn Talisman (*The Neverending Story*)

**W10:**

**W11:**

- Father "Fix-It", *Batteries Not Included* (1987)

**W12:**

- Tribbles (*Star Trek*)

---

**X1:**

- [Merlin game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_%28game%29)
- Possibly a bottle of Romulan Ale

**X2:**

- Mork, *Mork and Mindy*

**X3:**

- Susan Ivanova and Delenn, *Babylon 5*

**X4:**

- Annelids/worm coffee aliens from *Men In Black*

**X5:**

**X6:**

- [Bib Fortuna](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bib_Fortuna) (*Star Wars*)

**X7:**

- The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (*The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*)

**X8:**

- A Towel. "... the most massively useful thing an interstellar hitchhiker can have."
- Kira and Jen, continued in X9 (*The Dark Crystal*)
- [Dathon](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dathon) (*Star Trek: The Next Generation*, "Darmok")

**X9:**

- Jake (The Cat from Outer Space) [Also X10]
- Fizgig (The Dark Crystal)

**X10:**

- Barf (Spaceballs)

**X11:**

- Mother "Fix-It", *Batteries Not Included* (1987)

**X12:**

- A Porg (*Star Wars*)
- Puckmaren, *Flight of the Navigator* (1986)

---

**Y1:**

- [K-9](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/K9), *Doctor Who*

**Y2:**

**Y3:**

**Y4:**

- A [little golden fuzzy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Fuzzy), [*Little Fuzzy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Fuzzy) and subsequent works by H. Beam Piper (1962)

**Y5:**

**Y6:**

**Y7:**

**Y8:**

**Y9:**

- [Centauri](https://thelaststarfighter.fandom.com/wiki/Centauri), *The Last Starfighter* (1984)

**Y10:**

- Acroyear, Micronauts
- Bug, Micronauts (continued in Z10)

**Y11:**

- Wheems & Jetsam "Fix-It" (x2), *Batteries Not Included* (1987)
- Alien from *They Live*, seen through the special sunglasses

**Y12:**

---

**Z1:**

- Frank the Pug, *Men In Black*

**Z2:**

**Z3:**

- Dr Zira, *Planet of the Apes* (1968)

**Z4:**

**Z5:**

- Robot Monster, *Robot Monster* (1953)

**Z6:**

**Z7:**

- Norris-Thing, *The Thing*

**Z8:**

- Dalgoda, comic book, Jan Strnad and Dennis Fujitake from Fantagraphics

**Z9:**

**Z10:**

- Bug, from Micronauts (also in Y10)
- Jeff Carlisle logo

**Z11:**

**Z12:**

- Flotsam "Fix-It", (*Batteries Not Included*, 1987)
- Shrunken Kids, (*Honey I Shrunk The Kids*, 1989)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89632/discussion-on-answer-by-stormblessed-who-are-the-numerous-patrons-of-the-warp).