# Who are the 378 mutants in this image?

Tags: marvel, x-men, character-identification

Recently a [new series of covers](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2019/08/26/marvel-x-men-every-mutant-ever-variants/#1) revealed the picture of "every" mutant.

I am attempting to build a comprehensive list of these mutants, who could potentially be a threat to homo-sapiens. A registry, if you will. And I'd like to identify these 378 known terrorists..err mutants. I'm just a concerned citizen.

[image: the mutants]

Comment: Yup, this is going to be hard to answer without a number system or at least a grid

Comment: It would be useful if whatever image is used includes the captions (and cut lines) for each of the 6 divisions of the original, since that would be very useful for limiting the scope of each identification.  Actually, that would also make it easier to follow a numbering scheme.

Comment: Making a graphed version currently, like I did for [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/205117/102999).

Comment: Since we're down to the last 23, I thought I'd upload an easier one to look up only the remaining ones that don't have a tentative identification: https://i.imgur.com/dtJZZhG.jpg (The last is because I'm sure one is Persuasion, but I'm not 100% sure on which).  Also, this contains a better look, from a second source, at a few faces which were cut off by the cover edges.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Based on this numbering:

[image: 394]

The following appear (links attempt to give best reference for that particular 'look', a "+" indicates not technically considered a mutant):

1. [Absalom](http://bit.ly/2kyoyEv)?
2. [Madin](http://bit.ly/2kvSots)
3. [Battering Ram](http://bit.ly/2kupKZy)
4. [Chicken Wings](http://bit.ly/2lyOO1Y)
5. [Hump](http://bit.ly/2lEmQSw)
6. [Abyss](http://bit.ly/2k5vn0g)
7. [Living Monolith](http://bit.ly/2ki8bvX)
8. [La Nuit](http://bit.ly/2m1kbT0)
9. [Adam X](http://bit.ly/2kxgHaf)
10. Magneto
11. [Feral](http://bit.ly/2m3nKIl)
12. [Karasu](https://marvel.fandom.com/Karasu-Tengu_(Earth-616))
13. [Joe Bugs](http://bit.ly/2km2HjS)
14. [Negasonic Teenage Warhead](http://bit.ly/2lBkYty)
15. [Oya](https://marvel.fandom.com/Idie_Okonkwo_(Earth-616))?
16. [Onyxx](https://marvel.fandom.com/Sidney_Green_(Earth-616))
17. [Skids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skids_(comics))
18. [Hijack](https://marvel.fandom.com/David_Bond_(Earth-616))?
19. [Metalhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalhead_(comics))
20. ?
21. [Harry Leland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Leland)
22. [Ever](https://marvel.fandom.com/Ever_(Earth-616))
23. [Smart Alec](https://marvel.fandom.com/Alexander_Thorne_(Earth-616)) +
24. [Silver Samurai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Samurai)
25. [Shark-Girl](http://bit.ly/2lXH9u1)
26. Cyclops
27. [Orphan](https://marvel.fandom.com/Guy_Smith_(Earth-616))
28. [Loa](https://marvel.fandom.com/Alani_Ryan_(Earth-616))
29. [Jazz](https://marvel.fandom.com/John_Zander_(Earth-616))
30. [Revelation](https://marvel.fandom.com/Revelation_(Earth-616))
31. [Mentallo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mentallo)
32. [Obsidian](http://bit.ly/2m3avrf)
33. [Phat](https://marvel.fandom.com/William_Robert_Reilly_(Earth-616))
34. [Mysterious Fan Boy](https://marvel.fandom.com/Arnold_Lundberg_(Earth-616))
35. [Madison Jeffries](https://marvel.fandom.com/Madison_Jeffries_(Earth-616))
36. [Sluk](https://marvel.fandom.com/Byron_Spencer_(Earth-616))
37. [Wolf Cub](https://marvel.fandom.com/Nicholas_Gleason_(Earth-616))
38. [Omerta](https://marvel.fandom.com/Paul_Provenzano_(Earth-616))?
39. [Projector](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix6/projectoracolyte.htm)
40. [Prof X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_X) (House of X)
41. [Radius](https://marvel.fandom.com/Jared_Corbo_(Earth-616))
42. [Aurora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora_(comics))
43. [Javitz](https://marvel.fandom.com/Isaac_Javitz_(Earth-616))
44. [Pixie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixie_(X-Men))
45. [Skin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_(Marvel_Comics))
46. [Quill](https://marvel.fandom.com/Maxwell_Jordan_(Earth-616))
47. [Leech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_(comics))
48. [Blob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_(comics))
49. [Paradigm](https://marvel.fandom.com/Paradigm_(Earth-616))
50. [Persuasion](https://marvel.fandom.com/Kara_Killgrave_(Earth-616))
51. [Layla Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layla_Miller)
52. [Lifeguard](https://uncannyxmen.net/characters/lifeguard)
53. [Erg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erg_(comics))
54. [Healer](https://marvel.fandom.com/Healer_(Morlock)_(Earth-616))
55. ?
56. [Vanguard](https://marvel.fandom.com/Alexi_Shostakov_(Earth-616)) ([costume](https://tinyurl.com/y6ntag98))
57. [Aries](https://marvel.fandom.com/Aries_(Marauders)_(Earth-616))
58. [Scorpion Boy](https://marvel.fandom.com/Rico_(Mutant)_(Earth-616))
59. [Fabian Cortez](https://x-men.fandom.com/Fabian_Cortez)
60. [Stitch](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/stitch/4005-26324/)
61. [Hellion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellion_(Marvel_Comics))
62. [Scanner](https://marvel.fandom.com/Sarah_Ryall_(Earth-616))
63. [Prodigy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prodigy_(David_Alleyne))
64. [Big Bertha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bertha_(comics))
65. [Glob Herman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_Herman)
66. [Caliban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caliban_(Marvel_Comics))
67. [Blow-Hard](https://marvel.fandom.com/Blow-Hard_(Earth-616))
68. [Murmur](https://marvel.fandom.com/Arlette_Truffaut_(Earth-616))
69. [Collective Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_Man)
70. Flashback's Duplicate
71. [Flashback](https://marvel.fandom.com/Gardner_Monroe_(Earth-616))
72. [Banshee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banshee_(comics))
73. [Broo](https://marvel.fandom.com/Broo_(Earth-616))
74. [Bloke](https://marvel.fandom.com/Mickey_Tork_(Earth-616))
75. [Micromax](https://marvel.fandom.com/Scott_Wright_(Earth-616))
76. [Puck](https://marvel.fandom.com/Zuzha_Yu_(Earth-616)) (Zuzha Yu)? (coloring issue)
77. [Gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway_(comics))
78. [Darwin](http://bit.ly/2lBjLT2)?
79. [Storm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_(Marvel_Comics))
80. [Polaris](http://bit.ly/2m4C4QQ)
81. [Firefist](http://bit.ly/2kv5yqJ)
82. [Dr. Swaine](https://marvel.fandom.com/Brian_Swaine_(Earth-616))
83. [Lacuna](http://bit.ly/2lRjSu0)
84. [Shadow King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_King) (Amahl Farouk)
85. [Shadowcat](http://bit.ly/2lDtacK)
86. [Emplate](https://marvel.fandom.com/Marius_St._Croix_(Earth-616))
87. [Transonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transonic_(comics))
88. [Multiple Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/James_Madrox_(Earth-616))
89. [Ricochet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricochet_(comics))
90. [Eye-Boy](https://marvel.fandom.com/Trevor_Hawkins_(Earth-616))
91. [Franklin Richards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_Richards_(comics))
92. Vance Astrovik/[Justice](https://marvel.fandom.com/Vance_Astrovik_(Earth-616))
93. [Sunder](https://villains.fandom.com/Sunder_(Marvel))
94. [Frenzy](https://marvel.fandom.com/Joanna_Cargill_(Earth-616))
95. [Thunderbird](https://marvel.fandom.com/John_Proudstar_(Earth-616)) (John Proudstar)
96. [Maggot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maggott)
97. [Iceman](http://bit.ly/2m4tZeZ)
98. [Pyro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyro_(Marvel_Comics))
99. [Peepers](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix3/peepermutantforce.htm)
100. [Namor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namor)
101. [Bishop](https://marvel.fandom.com/Lucas_Bishop_(Earth-1191))
102. [Scaleface](https://marvel.fandom.com/Scaleface_(Earth-616))
103. [Bevatron](https://marvel.fandom.com/Fabian_Marechal-Julbin_(Earth-616))
104. [Plazm](https://marvel.fandom.com/Plazm_(Earth-616))
105. [Vindaloo](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/vindaloo/4005-15069/)?
106. [Mandrill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandrill_(comics))
107. [Tri-Joey](https://marvel.fandom.com/Joseph_Bricklemoore_(Earth-616)) +
108. [Hemingway](https://marvel.fandom.com/Hemingway_(Earth-616))
109. [Darkstar](https://marvel.fandom.com/Laynia_Petrovna_(Earth-616))
110. [Sunfire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunfire_(comics))
111. [Randall](https://marvel.fandom.com/Randall_(Earth-1191))
112. [Vulcan](https://marvel.fandom.com/Gabriel_Summers_(Earth-616))
113. [Magma](https://marvel.fandom.com/Amara_Aquilla_(Earth-616))
114. [Hazard](https://marvel.fandom.com/Carter_Ryking_(Earth-616))
115. [Shattertar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatterstar)
116. Empath?
117. [Threnody](https://marvel.fandom.com/Melody_Jacobs_(Earth-616))
118. [Surge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surge_(comics))
119. [Famine](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix6/famine_apocalypse.htm)
120. [Pestilence](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix6/pestilence_morlock.htm)
121. [Dead Girl](https://marvel.fandom.com/Dead_Girl_(Moonbeam)_(Earth-616))
122. [Fever Pitch](https://marvel.fandom.com/Fever_Pitch_(Earth-616))
123. Ch’vayre
124. [Warpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warpath_(comics))
125. [Thornn](https://marvel.fandom.com/Lucia_Callasantos_(Earth-616))
126. [Bedlam](https://uncannyxmen.net/characters/bedlam)
127. [Neophyte](https://marvel.fandom.com/Simon_Hall_(Earth-616))
128. [Stepford Cuckoos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepford_Cuckoos)
129. [Forge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forge_(comics))
130. [Exodus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exodus_(comics))
131. [Evangeline Whedon](https://marvel.fandom.com/Evangeline_Whedon_(Earth-616))
132. ?
133. [Meltdown](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/boom-boom/4005-2159/) (probably, can't find reference for exact outfit)
134. [Rictor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rictor)
135. [Daken](https://marvel.fandom.com/Akihiro_(Earth-616))
136. [Sunpyre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunpyre)
137. [Zeitgeist](https://marvel.fandom.com/Axel_Cluney_(Earth-616))
138. [Spike](https://marvel.fandom.com/Darian_Elliott_(Earth-616))
139. [Goldballs](https://marvel.fandom.com/Fabio_Medina_(Earth-616))
140. [Omega Red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_Red)
141. [Mother Inferior](https://marvel.fandom.com/Mother_Inferior_(Earth-616))
142. [Mesmero](https://marvel.fandom.com/Mesmero_(Vincent)_(Earth-616))?
143. [Azazel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azazel_(Marvel_Comics))
144. [Snowbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowbird_(comics)) +
145. [Morph](https://marvel.fandom.com/Kevin_Sidney_(Earth-1081))
146. [M](https://marvel.fandom.com/Monet_St._Croix_(Earth-616)) (one of many costumes [here](https://tinyurl.com/yylzwxr2))
147. [Lexi](http://bit.ly/2kkVEIc)?
148. [El Guapo](https://marvel.fandom.com/Robbie_Rodriguez_(Earth-616))
149. [Succubus](https://marvel.fandom.com/Succubus_(Mutant)_(Earth-616))
150. [Bling!](http://bit.ly/2kAnrUP)
151. [Jubilee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jubilee_(comics))
152. ?
153. [Ursa Major](https://marvel.fandom.com/Mikhail_Ursus_(Earth-616))
154. [Dust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_(comics))
155. [Havok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havok_(comics))
156. [Joseph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_(comics)), Magneto-clone
157. [Mant](https://marvel.fandom.com/Thomas_Williams_(Earth-616))
158. [Tempus](https://marvel.fandom.com/Eva_Bell_(Earth-616))
159. [Whiz Kid](https://marvel.fandom.com/Takeshi_Matsuya_(Earth-616))
160. [Bulk](http://bit.ly/2lXJQvE) or [Slab](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/slab/4005-15785/)
161. [Rockslide](http://bit.ly/2k4iWBL)
162. [Beautiful Dreamer](http://bit.ly/2lAax9C)
163. [Genesis](https://marvel.fandom.com/Evan_Sabahnur_(Earth-616))
164. [Xorn](https://marvel.fandom.com/Kuan-Yin_Xorn_(Earth-616))
165. [Gambit](http://bit.ly/2m3rxp1)
166. [Hope Summers](https://marvel.fandom.com/Hope_Summers_(Earth-616))
167. [Toad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toad_(comics))
168. [Apocalypse](http://bit.ly/2lzsrt7)
169. [Sabretooth](http://bit.ly/2lHeaKO)
170. [Sebastian Shaw](https://marvel.fandom.com/Sebastian_Shaw_(Earth-616))
171. [Changeling](https://marvel.fandom.com/Changeling_(Earth-616))
172. [Warlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warlock_(New_Mutants))
173. Stevie Hunter
174. [Rogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_(comics))
175. [Nuwa](https://marvel.fandom.com/Nuwa_(Earth-616))
176. [Match](https://marvel.fandom.com/Ben_Hammil_(Earth-616))?
177. [Maverick](https://marvel.fandom.com/Christoph_Nord_(Earth-616))
178. [Meld](https://marvel.fandom.com/Jeremiah_Muldoon_(Earth-616))?
179. [Mastermind](http://bit.ly/2lD6XeW)
180. [Whirlwind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whirlwind_(comics))
181. [No-Girl](https://marvel.fandom.com/Martha_Johansson_(Earth-616))
182. [Avalanche](https://marvel.fandom.com/Dominikos_Petrakis_(Earth-616))
183. ?
184. [MeMe](https://marvel.fandom.com/MeMe_(Morlock)_(Earth-616))
185. [Marrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marrow_(comics))
186. ?
187. [Vivisector](https://marvel.fandom.com/Myles_Alfred_(Earth-616))
188. [Damian Tryp](https://marvel.fandom.com/Dafydd_ap_Andras_(Earth-6124))
189. [Vulpine](https://marvel.fandom.com/Roja_Sanford_(Earth-616))
190. ?
191. [Wither](https://marvel.fandom.com/Kevin_Ford_(Earth-616))?
192. [Monte](https://marvel.fandom.com/Monte_(Earth-616))
193. Chance (Fallen Angels)
194. [Wallflower](https://marvel.fandom.com/Laurie_Collins_(Earth-616))
195. [Fantomex](https://marvel.fandom.com/Charlie_Cluster-7_(Earth-616))
196. [Tommy](https://marvel.fandom.com/Tommy_(Morlock)_(Earth-616))
197. [Johnny Dee](https://marvel.fandom.com/Johnny_Dee_(Earth-616))
198. [Alchemy](https://marvel.fandom.com/Thomas_Jones_(Earth-616))
199. [Irving](https://marvel.fandom.com/Irving_(Morlock)_(Earth-616))
200. [Velocidad](https://marvel.fandom.com/Gabriel_Cohuelo_(Earth-616))
201. [Lightning Bug](https://marvel.fandom.com/Matt_Corbin_(Earth-616))
202. [The Fittest](https://marvel.fandom.com/Frederick_Slade_(Earth-616))
203. [Outlaw](https://marvel.fandom.com/Inez_Temple_(Earth-616))
204. ?
205. [Darkling](https://marvel.fandom.com/Henrique_Gallante_(Earth-616))
206. [Annalee](https://marvel.fandom.com/Annalee_(Earth-616))
207. [Tether](https://marvel.fandom.com/Tether_(Earth-616))
208. [Coda](https://marvel.fandom.com/Coda_(Marauders)_(Earth-616))
209. [Brute](https://marvel.fandom.com/Brute_(Morlock)_(Earth-616))
210. [Auric](https://marvel.fandom.com/Zhao_Tang_(Earth-616)) (weird coloring, see 222)
211. [Smoke](https://marvel.fandom.com/Smoke_(Earth-616))
212. [Tempo](https://marvel.fandom.com/Heather_Tucker_(Earth-616))
213. [Lightbright](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/lightbright/4005-13748/)
214. [Riptide](https://marvel.fandom.com/Janos_Quested_(Earth-616))
215. [Feedback](http://bit.ly/2k7cbPO)
216. [Siena Blaze](https://marvel.fandom.com/Siena_Blaze_(Earth-616))
217. [Tyler Dayspring](https://uncannyxmen.net/characters/dayspring-tyler)
218. [Sumo](https://marvel.fandom.com/Jun_Tenta_(Earth-616))
219. [Ziggy Karst](https://marvel.fandom.com/Ziggy_Karst_(Earth-616))
220. [Mole](https://marvel.fandom.com/Mole_(Morlock)_(Earth-616))
221. [Unuscione](https://x-men.fandom.com/Unuscione)
222. [Silver](https://marvel.fandom.com/Jimon_Tang_(Earth-616)) (weird coloring, see 210)
223. [Azimuth](https://marvel.fandom.com/Azimuth_(Marauders)_(Earth-616))
224. [Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(Marvel_Comics))
225. [Cassandra Nova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassandra_Nova) +
226. [Cipher](https://marvel.fandom.com/Alisa_Tager_(Earth-616))
227. [Firestar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firestar_(Marvel_Comics))
228. [Stacy X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacy_X)
229. [Esme Cuckoo](https://marvel.fandom.com/Esme_Cuckoo_(Earth-616))
230. [Sprite](https://marvel.fandom.com/Jia_Jing_(Earth-616))
231. [Tito Bohusk](http://bit.ly/2lzTrJ0)
232. [Marked Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/Marked_Man_(Earth-616))?
233. [Sabra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabra_(comics))
234. [Loss](https://marvel.fandom.com/Loss_(Gene_Nation)_(Earth-616))
235. [Bliss](https://marvel.fandom.com/Bliss_(Morlock)_(Earth-616))
236. [Skinless Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/Harry_Pizer_(Earth-616))
237. [Sanjar Javeed](https://marvel.fandom.com/Sanjar_Javeed_(Earth-616))/Death
238. [Sage](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/sage/4005-4559/)
239. [Viper](https://marvel.fandom.com/Ophelia_Sarkissian_(Earth-616)) +
240. [Cyber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyber_(Marvel_Comics))
241. [Mondo](https://marvel.fandom.com/Mondo_(Earth-616))
242. [Coach](https://marvel.fandom.com/Coach_(Earth-616))?
243. [Jennifer Ransome](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/jennifer-ransome/4005-15022/)
244. [Mortis](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix/londonloisdaz.htm)
245. [Andrea von Strucker](https://marvel.fandom.com/Fenris_(Earth-616))
246. [Andreas von Strucker](https://marvel.fandom.com/Fenris_(Earth-616))
247. [Callisto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callisto_(comics))
248. [Armor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armor_(comics))
249. [Mist Mistress](https://marvel.fandom.com/Mist_Mistress_(Earth-616))
250. ?
251. Trance (255)'s Astral Form
252. [Anarchist](https://marvel.fandom.com/Tike_Alicar_(Earth-616))
253. [Black Tom Cassidy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Tom_Cassidy)?
254. [Chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamber_(comics))
255. [Trance](https://marvel.fandom.com/Hope_Abbott_(Earth-616))
256. [Kid Omega](https://marvel.fandom.com/Quintavius_Quire_(Earth-616))
257. [Amp](https://marvel.fandom.com/Amp_(Michelle)_(Earth-616))
258. [Beak](https://marvel.fandom.com/Barnell_Bohusk_(Earth-616))
259. [Ernst](https://www.marvel.com/characters/ernst) or [Qwerty](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix4/qwertymorlocks.htm)
260. [Choir](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix6/choir.htm)
261. [Delphi](https://marvel.fandom.com/Delphi_(Morlock)_(Earth-616))
262. [Zeek](https://marvel.fandom.com/Zeek_(Earth-616))?
263. [Magik](https://marvel.fandom.com/Illyana_Rasputina_(Earth-616))
264. [Sunspot](https://marvel.fandom.com/Roberto_da_Costa_(Earth-616))
265. [Scalphunter](https://marvel.fandom.com/John_Greycrow_(Earth-616))
266. [Selene](https://marvel.fandom.com/Selene_Gallio_(Earth-616))
267. [Ape](https://marvel.fandom.com/Ape_(Morlock)_(Earth-616))
268. [Wolverine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_(character))
269. [Proteus](http://bit.ly/2lHCHPS)? (wide variation in drawing styles)
270. [Gin Genie](https://marvel.fandom.com/Beckah_Parker_(Earth-616))
271. [Washout](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/washout/4005-43008/)
272. [Doorman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doorman_(comics))
273. [Wolfsbane](http://bit.ly/2lXJBAK)
274. [Portal](https://marvel.fandom.com/Charles_Little_Sky_(Earth-616))
275. [Arlo Summers](https://marvel.fandom.com/Arlo_Summers_(Earth-616))
276. [Beast](http://bit.ly/2koa5LD)
277. [Diamond Lil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_Lil_(Marvel_Comics))
278. [Hindsight](https://marvel.fandom.com/Nathaniel_Carver_(Earth-616))
279. [Catseye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catseye_(comics))
280. [Wild Child](https://marvel.fandom.com/Kyle_Gibney_(Earth-616))
281. [Cypher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cypher_(Marvel_Comics))
282. [Jean Grey](http://bit.ly/2kzdgQm)
283. [Domino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_(comics))
284. [Michael Pointer](https://marvel.fandom.com/Michael_Pointer_(Earth-616))?
285. [Tarot](https://uncannyxmen.net/characters/tarot)
286. [Karma](https://marvel.fandom.com/Xi%27an_Coy_Manh_(Earth-616))
287. [Thumbelina](https://marvel.fandom.com/Kristina_Anderson_(Earth-616))
288. [Primal](https://marvel.fandom.com/Teon_Macik_(Earth-616))
289. [Dani Moonstar](http://bit.ly/2m5OtE8)
290. [Siryn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siryn)
291. [Angel Salvadore](https://marvel.fandom.com/Angel_Salvadore_(Earth-616))
292. [Sojobo](https://marvel.fandom.com/Sojobo-Tengu_(Earth-616))?
293. [Anole](https://marvel.fandom.com/Victor_Borkowski_(Earth-616))
294. ?
295. [Synch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synch_(comics))
296. [Mystique](http://bit.ly/2kALSBJ)
297. [Colossus](http://bit.ly/2lJQcP2)
298. [Squidface](http://bit.ly/2k28NFH) + (Face shape seen [here](http://bit.ly/2lF5O6q))
299. [Phantazia](https://marvel.fandom.com/Eileen_Harsaw_(Earth-616))
300. ?
301. [Flatman](http://bit.ly/2ko9pG4)
302. [Legion](http://bit.ly/2k3l38U)
303. [Arclight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arclight_(comics))
304. ?
305. ?
306. [Prism](https://marvel.fandom.com/Prism_(Robbie)_(Earth-616))
307. [Masque](https://marvel.fandom.com/Masque_(Morlock)_(Earth-616))
308. [Strong Guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Guy)
309. [Cecilia Reyes](https://marvel.fandom.com/Cecilia_Reyes_(Earth-616))
310. [Amelia Voght](https://marvel.fandom.com/Amelia_Voght_(Earth-616))
311. [Destiny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destiny_(Irene_Adler))
312. [Stinger](https://uncannyxmen.net/characters/stinger)
313. [Luca Aldine](https://marvel.fandom.com/Luca_Aldine_(Earth-616))
314. [Blockbuster](https://marvel.fandom.com/Michael_Baer_(Earth-616))
315. [Nature Girl](https://marvel.fandom.com/Lin_Li_(Earth-616))
316. [Harpoon](https://marvel.fandom.com/Kodiak_Noatak_(Earth-616))
317. [Mr. M](http://bit.ly/2lFzoZF)?
318. [Samson](https://marvel.fandom.com/Samson_(Morlock)_(Earth-616))
319. [Lady Mastermind](https://marvel.fandom.com/Regan_Wyngarde_(Earth-616))
320. [Cannonball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannonball_(comics))
321. [Typhoid Mary](https://marvel.fandom.com/Mary_Walker_(Earth-616))
322. [Sycamore](https://marvel.fandom.com/James_Hutchinson_(Earth-616))
323. [Dragoness](https://marvel.fandom.com/Tamara_Kurtz_(Earth-616)) (mask usually has a visor but it is occasionally drawn with separate eyes, shape is distinctive)
324. [Boost](https://marvel.fandom.com/Boost_(Earth-616))
325. [Mammomax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammomax)
326. [Grimlock](https://marvel.fandom.com/Grimlock_(Earth-616))
327. Highbrow (of Manikin)
328. Apeman (of Manikin)
329. [Blindfold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blindfold_(comics))
330. Chris Bradley
331. [Husk](http://bit.ly/2lM0Mp2)
332. [Tanya Trask](http://bit.ly/2k8By3z)
333. [Vessel](http://bit.ly/2lBkSCl)
334. [Saint Anna](https://marvel.fandom.com/Saint_Anna_(Anna)_(Earth-616))
335. [Manikin](https://marvel.fandom.com/Whitman_Knapp_(Earth-616))
336. [Carver](https://marvel.fandom.com/Carver_(Morlock)_(Earth-616))
337. [Berzerker](https://marvel.fandom.com/Ray_Carter_(Earth-616))
338. [Greymalkin](https://marvel.fandom.com/Jonas_Graymalkin_(Earth-616))
339. [Locus](https://marvel.fandom.com/Rayna_Piper_(Earth-616))
340. [Pete Wisdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pete_Wisdom) (probably, process of elimination)
341. [Skein](https://marvel.fandom.com/Sybil_Dvorak_(Earth-616)) (aka Gypsy Moth)
342. ?
343. [Mikhail Rasputin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Rasputin)
344. [Venus Dee Milo](https://marvel.fandom.com/Venus_Dee_Milo)
345. [Empyrean](https://marvel.fandom.com/Jonathan_Chambers_(Earth-616))
346. [Gentle](https://marvel.fandom.com/Nezhno_Abidemi_(Earth-616))
347. [Cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_(comics))
348. [Gargouille](https://marvel.fandom.com/Lavinia_LeBlanc_(Earth-616))
349. [Mindblast](https://marvel.fandom.com/Danielle_Forte_(Earth-616))
350. [Northstar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northstar_(comics))
351. [Lorelei Travers](http://bit.ly/2lEqXhq)
352. [Nightcrawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightcrawler_(comics))
353. [Moira MacTaggart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moira_MacTaggert)? (glasses shape match)  Or possibly [Creep](https://marvel.fandom.com/Marisol_Guerra_(Earth-616)) (glasses and hairstyle match)
354. [Vanisher](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/vanisher/4005-6756/images/)
355. [D'Gard](https://marvel.fandom.com/D%27Gard_(Earth-616))
356. [Microbe](https://marvel.fandom.com/Zachary_Smith_Jr._(Earth-616))
357. [Mr. Sinister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mister_Sinister) +
358. [Nekra](http://bit.ly/2lVyOHg)? (Based on widow's peak and possible topknot, should be chalk white)
359. [Icarus](https://marvel.fandom.com/Joshua_Guthrie_(Earth-616))
360. [Tar Baby](https://marvel.fandom.com/Tar_Baby_(Earth-616))
361. [Psylocke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psylocke)/[Kwannon](https://marvel.fandom.com/Revanche_(Kwannon)_(Earth-616)) Body
362. [Petra](https://marvel.fandom.com/Petra_(Earth-616))
363. [Kiden Nixon](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix3/kidennixonnyx.htm) (clothes and pacifier)
364. [Litterbug](https://marvel.fandom.com/Litterbug_(Earth-616))
365. [Jo](https://marvel.fandom.com/Jo_(Morlock)_(Earth-616))
366. [Rachel Summers](https://marvel.fandom.com/Rachel_Summers_(Earth-811))
367. [Thunderbird](http://bit.ly/2lKaEiP) (Neil Shaara)
368. [Missy](https://marvel.fandom.com/Missy_(Morlock)_(Earth-616))
369. [U-Go Girl](https://marvel.fandom.com/Edith_Sawyer_(Earth-616))
370. [Brain Cell](https://marvel.fandom.com/Brain_Cell_(Kevin)_(Earth-616))?
371. [Sack](https://marvel.fandom.com/Sack_(Earth-616))?
372. [X-23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-23)
373. [Membrain](https://marvel.fandom.com/Membrain_(Earth-616))
374. [Zero](https://marvel.fandom.com/Kenji_Uedo_(Earth-616))
375. [Maw](http://bit.ly/2kyxzO0)
376. [Gamesmaster](https://marvel.fandom.com/Gamesmaster_(Earth-616))
377. [Ent](https://marvel.fandom.com/Ent_(Earth-616))
378. [Gaia](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Gaia_(Earth-616))
379. [Shinobi Shaw](https://marvel.fandom.com/Shinobi_Shaw_(Earth-616))?
380. [Dazzler](http://bit.ly/2kpxT1F)
381. ?
382. [Emma Frost](http://bit.ly/2lJQ6a8)
383. [Crosta](https://marvel.fandom.com/Crosta_(Earth-616))
384. [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(comics))
385. [Elixir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elixir_(comics))
386. [Indra](https://marvel.fandom.com/Paras_Gavaskar_(Earth-616))
387. [Black Box](http://bit.ly/2kAsDIi)
388. [Dr Nemesis](https://marvel.fandom.com/James_Bradley_(Earth-616))
389. [La Lunatica](https://marvel.fandom.com/La_Lunatica_(Earth-928)) (2099)
390. [Corkscrew](https://marvel.fandom.com/Timmy_Glenn_(Earth-616))
391. [Lila Cheney](https://marvel.fandom.com/Lila_Cheney_(Earth-616))
392. [Kylun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kylun)
393. Captain Britain/[Betsy Braddock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psylocke)
394. Archangel

Comment: Okay I've officially broke Stack Exchange's character limit for an answer, so I can't add any more until we decide how to handle it (separate answer for 1-199 and for 200-394, I imagine?)

Comment: URL shorteners for the hyperlinks would also be an option, but that would mean that people can't see the links before clicking on them.

Comment: If at all possible, I think we should try to keep this into one answer. The Q&A format doesn't seem to work very well for part 1/part 2 answers, since there can't be an "accepted" answer and one part may get more upvotes than another. So if there's any way to keep this together, let's do it.

Comment: I changed to use an ordered list, which gives a bit nicer presentation, makes missing entries more obvious, and staves off the character limit for a little longer due to not needing newlines.

Comment: Just a note for future editors - `marvel.fandom.com` links work without the `/wiki` part.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the assist!  With this we'll probably be able to complete the list (if we do at all) without needing too many links shortened-to-impenetrability.

Comment: If we do run into the character limit again, we can also remove hyperlinks for well-known mutants like Magneto.

Comment: I figured that some of the ones we still needed to identify were from the relatively obscure [*X-Men 2099*](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/x-men-2099/4060-41504/characters/), but I only found #19 Metalhead (in his earlier hairless form) and #389 La Lunatica. I was especially surprised I couldn't find their leader, Desert Ghost (a.k.a. Xi'an Chi Xan). So either I missed those mutants, they exist but are using an appearance I'm not familiar with, or this isn't really *every* mutant ever.

Comment: Oh yeah, it's absolutely not 'every mutant ever' or anywhere close but it's still fun.  As for 2099, I've got  278 down as a possible Metalsmith 2099 but not sure.

Comment: Scratch that, 278 is Hindsight

Comment: Since we're down to the last 23, I thought I'd upload an easier one to look up only the remaining ones that don't have a tentative identification: i.imgur.com/dtJZZhG.jpg (The last is because I'm sure one is Persuasion, but I'm not 100% sure on which). Also, this contains a better look, from a second source, at a few faces which were cut off by the cover edges.